# React Native project can't be open with android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm a newbie to react native. I started a new project and followed all the steps. I had Android Studio before and I started the emulator with it. After running `npx react-native run-android` command I get this error.

```
**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 34s
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 34s**
```

Then I ran `abd -d` command and I get this.

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.6-6198805
Installed as C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25992), you can try running the following command on the root folder of your project:

`cd android  && ./gradlew installDevDebug && cd .. && react-native run-android --variant=DevDebug`

After this your project should run on your Android sucessfully.

If not, open your project with android studio one time, and then recompile with `react-native run-android`

If even after this all your project doesnt work, make sure you already have the `ANDROID_HOME` variable on your PATH variables

Comment: My problem was with adding the ANDROID_HOME in PATH variables. Thanks for the comment!!!